# Hide the Table td incase the JSON size is one

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I am forming a table from a JSON as shown below

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Participant</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ParticipantList">
        {{#each person in model}}
            <tr>
                <td> {{person.name}}</td>
                    <td> {{person.city}}</td>
            <td><img src="image.jpg" alt="Remove"></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
   </table>
</script>
```

Incase the size of JSON is 1 (one) , how can i hide the Remove td (last td)

http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/1805/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by a simple computed property. The process is implemented in the `IndexController`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/1924/)

**Templates:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
   {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Participant</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ParticipantList">
        {{#each person in model}}
            <tr>
                <td> {{person.name}}</td>
                <td> {{person.city}}</td>
                {{#if ismorethanone}}
                     <td><img src="image.jpg" alt="Remove" {{action "removeUser" person.name}}></td>
                {{/if}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
   </table>
</script>
```

**JS part :**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [ {"name": "John", "city": "New York"},
                {"name": "SAAA","city": "California"},
                {"name": "Vignesh","city": "India"}]
    }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    ismorethanone : function(){
            return this.get("model").length>1;
    }.property("model.length"),

    actions :
    {
        removeUser:function(name){
            var model = this.get("model").filter(function(obj){
                 return obj.name!=name;
            });
            this.set("model",model);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if` and `eq` ember helpers like this:

```
 {{#if (eq model.length 1)}}
        <td><img src="image.jpg" alt="Remove"></td>
 {{/if}}
```

Or you could have a computed property in your controller that hides/shows the remove button like this:

```
//YourController.js
hideRemoveBtn: Ember.computed.equal('person.length', 1)

//html 
 {{#unless hideRemoveBtn}}
        <td><img src="image.jpg" alt="Remove"></td>
 {{/unless}}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you , The first option is not working getting Expecting 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'
    at Parser.parseError (handlebars-v1.1.2.js:777)

Comment: This is more a handlebars Parse error than a logic one. You should check if you are compiling the template the right way. check this http://handlebarsjs.com/installation.html